# Create a wiki page in gitlab

Tags: wiki, gitlab

I'm trying to create a simple wiki page on gitlab. Anyone knows of any good tutorials that could assist me in achieving that? I tried searching google for any tutorials but could not find any that are relevant.

Comment: Strangely difficult to find any wiki related documentation on gitlab!

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/wiki/

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://pad.haroopress.com/ as an editor, to see how it will look like in a wiki gitlab page.
In the bottom-left corner is a button, when you hit that button, you will get the markdown help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for page not the wikipage (if you are looking for wiki page you can create wiki page from the menu wiki)

if you are looking for Page:

Login to your GitLab account and create project under your username git the repo name as yourusername.gitlab.io

create create index.html,cssfiles,js files, and **.gitlab-ci.yml** push the files to gitlab it will build your page

you can opn you page in browser like yourusername.gitlab.io check this example http://wiki.workassis.com/how-to-create-gitlab-pages/