# How to create a wiki-page using GitLab API

Tags: api, gitlab, wiki

I want to create a repository/project in GitLab via API (that works of course) and then I want to add a WIKI page (with content) for that project.

There seems to be no separate WIKI API. 
One way could be to use the http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/api/repository_files.html#create-new-file-in-repository but what would be the id of the wiki-repository? if it even has an ID?

An alternative way is to clone the wiki repo, using the path of the repo suffixed by `.wiki.git` but that seems to be impractical if everything else is done using API requests :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257497/create-a-wiki-page-in-gitlab/37589885#37589885